# Navigation with header dropdown works on expo snack but doesn't on CLI

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**UPDATE with FIX: It was a named import error. Make sure to not use {} imports when you export default components**

Navigation stack with a header dropdown works on snack expo but I get a "Invariant violation: ... Check render method of ..." error when I build a simulator on CLI

I've tried adding or removing curly brackets from my imports but it's no use. I suspect it might be something about withNavigation exports in the components or import/exports in the navigation stack

https://snack.expo.io/@kkarakas/kkarakas-snack

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a named import error. Make sure to mostly not use {} imports on components